# Getting Ubuntu server to resolv new IP for a host name

Tags: networking, server, 14.04, hosts

I run a minecraft server on ubuntu 14.04 LTS on vm's using virtual box. In order for players to connect, their 'account' must be checked with Mojang, at sessionserver.mojang.com. The problem is, the ip that this points to changes once in a while.

I have no idea why, maybe system load, etc. But although I have added to the /etc/resolv.conf file (by editing /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head)
[search sessionserver.mojang.com], without brackets, whenever the ip to sessionserver.mojang.com changes, players can't log in, because my OS isn't resolving new ip.

How/what do I need to do to fix this, and have my settings correct?

Comment: How do you edit in the new IP address when it changes?

Comment: Strange thing is I never had this issue in 12.04 LTS.

Comment: [You could set an alias](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102660/hosts-file-is-it-incorrect-to-have-the-same-ip-address-on-multiple-lines), but [probably not on multiple lines](http://serverfault.com/questions/429839/assign-multiple-ips-to-1-entry-in-hosts-file)

Comment: If you figured it out, why not post your answer